# How do I fill the username field in a HTML page based on a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I am looking to create a tool for testers that makes their job a bit easier.
Currently they have Excel sheets with a column with an understandable name that maps to a numeric ID.

The numeric ID is the actual login name, so they look up the naem in the excel file and copy it to the username field.

After a few times this gets pretty tedious.

I want to make a JS script for Tamper Monkey that populates the username and password fields on the login page (of which I cannot edit the source , hence me using Tamper Monkey) based on a dropdown menu that shows the testers the list of understandable names and based on their choice populates the username field with the correct numeric ID.

I have tried the following:

```
 $('#username').attr('value', '4000021865');
 $('#password').attr('value', 'Test');
```

And this logs me in for one user.

But I can't find any working examples online of a dropdown based field population for TamperMonkey and I have no idea where to start.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a template I can re-use that does exactly what I need.

```
 // ==UserScript==
 // @name        facebook login
 // @namespace   http://123.123
 // @include     https://www.facebook.com/*
 // @version     1
 // @require     http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js
 // @require     http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
 // @resource    bt 
 http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
 // @resource    bt-theme 
 http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
 // @grant       GM_addStyle
 // @grant       GM_getResourceText
 // ==/UserScript==
(function() {
if ($('#login_form').length <= 0) {
    console.log('No login_form');
    return;
}

GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText("bt"));
GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText ("bt-theme"));
GM_addStyle("#menu1 a {text-align: left}");
var $loginbutton = $('#loginbutton');
var menu = '<span class="dropdown btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0 0 0 5px;">' +
           '<a id="drop4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" style="color: #FFF">User Selection ' +
           '<b class="caret"></b>' +
           '</a>' +
           '<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop4" role="menu">' +
           '<li>' +
           '<a href="#" role="menuitem">kaoyenchi</a>' +
           '</li>' +
           '<li>' +
           '<a href="#" role="menuitem">tcyc</a>' +
           '</li>' +
           '<li>' +
           '<a href="#" role="menuitem">fcwu</a>' +
           '</li>' +
           '</ul>' +
           '</span>'
$loginbutton.parent().append(menu);
var accounts = {};
accounts['fcwu'] = ['', ''];
accounts['kaoyenchi'] = ['', ''];
accounts['tcyc'] = ['', ''];
accounts['timy'] = ['', ''];
$('#menu1 a').click(function() {
    name = $(this).text()
    $('#email').attr('value', accounts[name][0]);
    $('#pass').attr('value', accounts[name][1]);
    $('#login_form').submit();
});

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `<select>` with a number of `<options>` you can do the same. `$('#selectId').attr('value', 'optionValue');`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g689n1d2/